# How to avoid code redundance in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I implemented `SendGrid` in my application, and inside the `Account` controller I have a method called `Register`. The method `Register` allow to the user to signup on the site, inside this method I have the following code:

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new
{
    userId = user.Id,
    token = code
}, protocol: Request.Scheme);

await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, _localizer["ConfirmYourEmail"], _localizer["ConfirmAccountTemplate", callbackUrl]);
```

as you can see I generate a confirmation code, and then I created a `callBackUrl` that the user can find inside the email for confirm the email address. At the end, I call `SendEmailAsync` which is essentially an implementation of the interface method of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services`.

Now the main problem is the following: I need to use the same code inside a `Repository` class, so not inside a `Controller`, is there a place to store this type of code without create redundance?

PS: I'm sorry if this question seems stupid, but I'm actually a newbie of `ASP.NET Core` and I want learn to how to create a good project structure.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: create a service abstraction and class that implements the repeated code and inject that where it is needed.

Comment: To understand you correctly, do you want to re-use the method to create the code or do you want to store the generated code?

Comment: @AntonToshik I need to reuse the method to create the code and send the email

Comment: You really would not want to re-use this code in a Repository, because this code depends on specific MVC features (Url.Action for instance).  You would probably want to make this a bit more generic, with allowing the output of those features to be passed into your method.  In most architectures, the data (repositories) are isolated from the UI (MVC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to reuse the method to create the code and send the email

This is a quick mark up I didn't test if this works. You want to make something of the following, and use this in Dependency Injection (DI). You might need to add `IUrlHelper` and  `IHttpContextAccessor`

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
    private HttpContext _ctx;
    private IUrlHelper _url;
    private IConfiguration _localizer;
    private IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public SomeClass(
        IUrlHelper url,
        IHttpContextAccessor ctx,
        IConfiguration config,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _ctx = ctx.HttpContext;
        _url = url;
        _localizer = config;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task SendEmailWithCode(string email)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        var callbackUrl = _url.Action(nameof(ResetPassword), "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code }, protocol:  _ctx.Request.Scheme);
        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, _localizer["ConfirmYourEmail"], _localizer["ConfirmAccountTemplate"], callbackUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, you suggest a specific folder where place this type of class? For the moment I've created a folder called `Dependencies`, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Rockj whatever works for you from this point on. Another thing you want to watch out for is bringing in dependencies multiple times. Let's say you bring up config in your controller and then you bring it up in your repository, I think it's better to pass it down in the constructor.

Comment: I always inject in the constructor, but maybe I misunderstood what you said